# Como concatenar CheckBox

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un pequeño inconveniente que no he podido resolver, resulta que me han dejado un programa en el cual se buscan letras (vocales) y esta me las muestras en un Textbox, la forma en que se busca es escribiendo en un TextBox aparte, luego se presiona un CheckBox la vocal a elegir y esta la busca, para luego saber cuantas veces se repite dicha vocal, el proceso para buscar y acumular las veces que se repite me da bien, pero el único inconveniente es que cuando quiero mostrar en mas de una letra en un TextBox aparte, esta solo me escribe una sola, no me concatena los resultados, por ejemplo: Si pongo la letra *hola*, cuando presiono la letra *a*, me la muestra pero al presionar el CheckBox de la letra *o*, se me borra la letra *a* y se me reemplaza por la letra *o*, he hecho un método demasiado largo como se muestra a continuación:

```
 private void muestraText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(checkBox1.Checked==true && checkBox2.Checked==false &&checkBox3.Checked==false && checkBox4.Checked==false&&checkBox5.Checked==false)
            {
                muestraText.Text = "A= " + Textos().ToString();
            }
            else if(checkBox1.Checked == false && checkBox2.Checked == true && checkBox3.Checked == false && checkBox4.Checked == false && checkBox5.Checked == false)
            {
                muestraText.Text = "E= " + Textos1().ToString();
            }
        }
```

Esto por poner un ejemplo, así lo he hecho, pero es demasiado largo y son bastante validaciones, existe alguna función que me permita realizar este trabajo de una manera eficiente?

Adjunto el método que ocupe para buscar las vocales:

```
public int Textos()
        {
            string palabra = string.Empty;
            int vocales = 0;

            palabra = texto.Text.ToLower();

            for (int i = 0; i < palabra.Length; i++)
            {
                if(palabra[i]=='a')
                {
                    vocales++;
                }
            }
            return vocales;
        }
```

Así para el resto de las palabras.

Adjunto imágenes para mejor comprensión:

[image: Primera parte]
[image: Segunda parte]

Ahí pueden observar el inconveniente, como pueden observar, en el text box no se me almacena cuantas veces se repite la vocal a, una vez se ha puesto en true el checkbox de la vocal o.

Comment: Supongo que solo es un problema de concatenación, trata probando de la siguiente forma:
muestraText.Text += "A= " + Textos().ToString()+" ";

Comment: Lo he intentado así, pero no me funciona.

Comment: Cual es el inconveniente ?

Comment: que quiere decir no me funciona? el control textbox es una clase como cualquier otra con una propiedad de tipo string (text) y cuando queres concatenar algo en un string, usas el simbolo +....

Comment: He resuelto el problema, lo explique en un comentario aparte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo he resuelto, por si alguien tiene esta duda en un futuro, he ocupado la funcion *Append*, de este modo:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(checkBox1.Checked==true)
        {
            if (texto.Text.Contains('a'))
            {
                muestraText.AppendText(" A= " + Textos().ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Por cada checkbox, se irá validando, debido a la funcionalidad crea una copia de la lista original y se añade un elemento a esa copia para luego borrar el array original.

Comment: Dale al check de la respuesta para que aparezca como contestada